# Handling Master Page Panels with Base Control Class

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-2.0

I have admin module. This module have one master page which has the no of panels at left side. I have to make this panels visible and invisible with base control class which is constructed in VB language. I'm working with asp.net 2.0 with c# web site.

Please give me idea how do i construct this base control class and manage panels with Master Page on link button click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll there is a plenty of opportunities to make it.
I'd prefer using of [facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Construct a class which would use VB class inside:

```
public newManageClass()
{
    private oldManagedVBClass _old;

    //.ctor
    public newManageClass()
    {
        _old = new oldManagedVBClass();
    }

    public void makePanelsVisible()
    {
        _old.MakePanelsVisible();
    }
}
```

And then you can use this class inside your master page as helper class.

Comment: can u give me more working samples which give me basic idea how i construct this kind of class and make panel visible and invisible.